# XML to Json not dealing with arrays the way I expect

Tags: xml, json, xml-serialization, jackson

I have an api that can have its response in either XML or Json.  For analyzing those results I created a single object that I want to populate for both json and xml.  Problem is my XML parser seems to deserialize the XML into Json in a slightly different format.

In the middle of my response is a nested array 
when I parse the JSON is looks like so

```
    "buckets":[
{"bucket":{"name":"soup","priority":10}},
{"bucket":{"name":"clams","priority":13}}],
```

And when I parse my XML to JSON it looks like so

```
"buckets":{"bucket":[
{"priority":"10","name":"soup"},
{"priority":"13","name":"clams"}]},
```

My single object created to hold this date has a private List buckets; Which the json parse handles fine while the xml parse throws an exception.

I am parsing both to the object like so 
myObject = mapper.readValue(SomeObject.get(0),myObject.class)

The json buckets works fine the xml does not.  I either need to parse the XML into similar format as the json or tell it maybe with an annotation to see buckets correctly

I parse my XML to json with this JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(cValue);

Comment: This is because XML can not express an array directly. It needs a repeating tag. (in your case bucket).  I wish someone had an answer to this. It would be great to be able to normalize the XML to a conventional JSON array.

Comment: If all else fails, write your own stream API based parser for the XML and you can make it do whatever you want. It's about twice as fast too, if you have performance concerns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain sub type information while serializing java objects using Jackson, without using wrapper class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27426327/maintain-sub-type-information-while-serializing-java-objects-using-jackson-with)